# Change titlebar height of an NSWindow

Tags: cocoa, macos, nswindow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the height of an NSWindow titlebar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639207/how-to-change-the-height-of-an-nswindow-titlebar)

I an trying to change the height of the titlebar of an NSWindow but without success.

Do you have any idea how I can achive this?

Thanks and regards,

Comment: Why do you want to do this? There is no public API, so would almost certainly get you banned from the App Store. Sure you're not just looking for `NSToolbar`?

Comment: I want to integrate a custom NSView inside the title bar (à la Reeder ou Mac App Store)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a textured window where you move the content view further down than usual. You may add views to the title bar by adding them to window.contentView.superview.

You may also draw a custom title bar by adding a view to window.contentView.superview. Make sure to add it behind the standard window controls.

Comment: It seems to be the good option. Thanks!

Comment: This actually is not the correct answer:
Using a textured window and increasing the top content border won't change the titlebar height. It only looks like it does but technically the height stays the same, you notice this when using the new Titlebar Accessory View.  

Additionally, adding views to the `window.contentView.superview` is not supported and causes a warning on OS X Yosemite.